# Logo issue in nav bar (trying to set it same width as navbar)

Tags: navbar

I have all my buttons of my nav bar and I have my logo already in top left but the bigger i make it, the thicker my nav bar becomes because i have padding set in css and my image URL is set in the Html:

## css

```
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px;
}
```

## HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home.asp">HOME</a></li>
    <li style="float:right">
      <a href="#logo">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="bandlogo" height="25px" width="50px">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to counter this issue like make a different `<ul>` or an addition to the li.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have text styles and image styles separate:

`#nav li .text {
    padding: x
}`

`#nav li .logo {
    padding: x
}`

Comment: Thank you, I inspired myself from your answer and created an <a class="logo" then in CSS made a .logo {

Comment: Good to know you found help in my answer, good luck with the rest of your website!